# How to extract members with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this string to parse and extract all elements between <>:

```
String text = "test user #myhashtag <@C5712|user_name_toto> <@U433|user_hola>";
```

I tried with this pattern, but it doesn't work (no result):

```
String pattern = "<@[C,U][0-9]+\\|[.]+>";
```

So in this example I want to extract:

- `<@C5712|user_name_toto>`
- `<@U433|user_hola>`

Then for each, I want to extract:

- `C` or `U` element
- ID (ie: `5712` or `433`)
- user name (ie: `user_name_toto`)

Thank you very much guys

Comment: You don't mention if these elements are of a particular type. It either is or it isn't. The general regex is `<@(.)([^|>])*\|([^|>]*)>`. So, a minimal form would be `<@x|>`. It's up to you to then determine the validity after a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The main problem I can see with your pattern is that it doesn't contain groups, hence retrieving parts of it will be impossible without further parsing.

You define numbered groups within parenthesis: `(partOfThePattern)`.
From Java 7 onwards, you can also define named groups as follows: `(?<theName>partOfThePattern)`.

- The second problem is that `[.]` corresponds to a literal dot, not an "any character" wildcard.
- The third problem is your last quantifier, which is greedy, therefore it would consume the whole rest of the string starting from the first username.

Here's a self-contained example fixing all that:

```
String text = "test user #myhashtag <@C5712|user_name_toto> <@U433|user_hola>";
//                            | starting <@
//                            | | group 1: any 1 char
//                            | |  | group 2: 1+ digits 
//                            | |  |     | escaped "|"
//                            | |  |     |   | group 3: 1+ non-">" chars, greedy
//                            | |  |     |   |       | closing >
//                            | |  |     |   |       | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<@(.)(\\d+)\\|([^>]+))>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf(
            "C or U? %s%nUser ID: %s%nUsername: %s%n", 
            m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)
        );
}
```

**Output**

```
C or U? C
User ID: 5712
Username: user_name_toto
C or U? U
User ID: 433
Username: user_hola
```

**Note**

I'm not validating `C` vs `U` here (gives you another `.` example).

You can easily replace the initial `(.)` with `(C|U)` if you only have either. You can also have the same with `([CU])`.

Comment: The third capture group should be ([^>]+) for better performance.

Comment: @Nevay can't claim any specific knowledge about that case, but I vaguely recall reluctant quantifiers should perform better than greedy... could you substantiate your claim? If you have any explanation I'm happy to amend my answer!

Comment: @Mena The reluctant version has to perform significantly more steps (it has to match against the next node on each single char of group 3), the greedy quantifier behaves like the possessive in this case. For this example its 28 steps vs 74 steps (https://regex101.com/r/XdNeWV/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/MzOQXr/1).

Comment: @Mena: is there a possibility to retrieve, for each group, the start index and end index matching in global string? ie: in my example the first group is matching between index 19 and 38 of initial string.

Comment: @anthony The Matcher#start(int) and Matcher#end(int) methods return the indices for the provided capture group.

Comment: @Nevay sorry I got busy. Looks like greedy towards end of input will perform better anyway, so fixing my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<@([CU])(\d{4})\|(\w+)>`

Where:

$1 --> C/U

$2 --> 5712/433

$3 --> user_name_toto/user_hola